# SOAP client cannot access the wsdl service present on the server of my corporate network

Tags: node.js, soap, wsdl

I am creating a soap client to connect to a server on my corporate network.As soon as I call a method I should get an output in the form of wsdl response.
So first i call the login method and it gives succesfully loggedin response but after that when i call any other function i get an error code from the service which means insufficient user rights.
When i don't use "process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0" "; i get 
'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'as response.

I don't know what the issue is because the soap client can login but after that any other function call gives response as "unsufficient user rights".

But the same service, i can access all the functions with a browser tool called Boomerang.

It would be of great help if anyone can give some suggestions and help me solve this frustrating issue.

Comment: Are you working with certificates or some kind of other authentication?

Comment: Actually i have a certificate which is needed for authorisation by the server ,there is a Login function in the WSDL  which needs to be called first before calling any other function.I can successfully login with the username and password but after that when i call any other function the response from the service is "Insufficient user rights".And the same service works well with SoapUI and Boomerang,all the functions give desired response.If this is a certificate issue why does it works fine with SoapUI?

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker did u get what i am trying to say??